# quasar : What is `Cordova id`？Where can I get it?

Tags: cordova, quasar, quasar-framework

This is the  first time I used [quasar](https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar),I am creating a project with Quasar CLI following the docs (https://quasar-framework.org/guide/app-installation.html)

```
λ quasar init quasar_demo
 Running command: vue init 'quasarframework/quasar-starter-kit' quasar_demo


? Project name (internal usage for dev) quasar_demo
? Project product name (official name) Quasar App
? Project description A Quasar Framework app
? Author
? Check the features needed for your project: ESLint, Vuex, Axios, Vue-i18n, IE11 support
? Pick an ESLint preset Standard
? Cordova id (disregard if not building mobile apps) org.cordova.quasar.app
```

The last command above told me to input Cordova id,what is `Cordova id` and Where can I get it?

Answer (score 9):

This is the unique identifier of your app (which is called `applicationId` or `packageName` for [Android](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id) and `CFBundleIdentifier` for [iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-102070)).
You can find the related cordova docs [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-cli/index.html#cordova-create-command).